# How to display assosiated data on second tab based on the data coming under first tab in ASP.NET MVC and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am using MVC application and entityframework,i have two table country and city which has PK_FK relation ship.In my UI i am using two tabs, first tab for countries and second for cities and both are displayed in  a grid which is in two partial views.Now what i have to achieve is if i click a country in first tab corresponding country cities should display in second tab rather than complete country cities.How to do that following is the existing code i have done

**controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{        
    return View();
}


public ActionResult _gridfirsttab()
{
    return PartialView(db.Countries.ToList());
}


public ActionResult _gridsecondtab()
{
    return PartialView(db.Citynews.ToList());
}
```

**Index view**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab Header 1</a></li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tab Header 2", "_gridsecondtab")</li>
    <li>>@Html.ActionLink("Tab Header 3", "_gridthirdtab")</li>
</ul>

<div id="tabs-1">
    @Html.Action("_gridfirsttab")
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I did like shown below but it is duplicating webgrid, may HTTPGET action also triggering how to prevent it

first partial view grid

```
@if (grid.HasSelection)
{
    conuntry = (firstmvc4.Models.Country)grid.Rows[grid.SelectedIndex].Value;

    @Html.Action("_gridsecondtab", new {id =conuntry.id })

}
```

and created one more HTTPPOST action of first grid

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult _gridsecondtab(int id)
    {
        // Find the customer by name
        var countries = db.Countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.id == id);

        // Get the customers products
        var cities = countries.Citynews;

        // Send products to the View to be rendered
        return PartialView(cities);
    }
```

But it is not properly working rather duplicating first grid itself

Comment: are you loading these tabs at the same time..?

Comment: @pjobs i modified my question, one tab is executing based on html.action and rest two are html.actionlink